# Here Maps URL for Google Chrome Search Omnibox

Tags: google-chrome, here-api, omnibox

For example, I can search Bing Maps from the Omnibox by using the following URL, where %s is in place of the query:

http://www.bing.com/maps/default.aspx?q=%s

Is there an equivalent URL for Here Maps?

Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go directly to HERE.com and add it as a search engine.

The current omni-box string is:

http://here.com/?cid=nokiamaps-fw-ilc-na-acq-na-opensearch-g0-na-1&plcsDl=search&q=%s

You could also use the !bang syntax from DuckDuckGo as shown:

[!here New York](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=!here%20new%20york&ia=about)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean to show search results in Here.com, You could achieve this via the HERE places API, for example to search

http://places.demo.api.here.com/places/v1/discover/search?at=52.521%2C13.3807&q=s&app_id=demo_qCG24t50dHOwrLQ&app_code=NYKC67ShPhQwqaydGIW4yg

-> Go to href of Item
http://places.demo.api.here.com/places/v1/places/loc-dmVyc2lvbj0xO3RpdGxlPVN0dXR0Z2FydDtsYXQ9NDguNzY3Njc7bG9uPTkuMTcxOTI7Y291bnRyeT1ERVU7c3RhdGU9QmFkZW4tV3VydHRlbWJlcmc7Y291bnR5PVN0dXR0Z2FydDtjYXRlZ29yeUlkPWFkbWluaXN0cmF0aXZlLXJlZ2lvbjtzb3VyY2VTeXN0ZW09aW50ZXJuYWw;context=Zmxvdy1pZD03MjMxMWU2MS0yNTJlLTU5OTMtOTZjOC0zNzZjN2QyNTdhZDBfMTQyNjE1NDg5NDk3N181MTczXzQ0MDEmYmJveD05LjAzNzMyJTJDNDguNjkyMDUlMkM5LjMxNTkzJTJDNDguODY2NTEmcmFuaz0x?app_id=demo_qCG24t50dHOwrLQ&app_code=NYKC67ShPhQwqaydGIW4yg

-> Go to "view" of Item

https://share.here.com/p/s-YmI9OS4wMzczMiUyQzQ4LjY5MjA1JTJDOS4zMTU5MyUyQzQ4Ljg2NjUxO2M9YWRtaW5pc3RyYXRpdmUtcmVnaW9uO2xhdD00OC43NzkyODtsb249OS4xNzY2MztuPVN0dXR0Z2FydDt6PTEyO2g9MTE0MDFh